# how to get 100% test coverage for apex class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I tried to get up below class coverage from 62% to 100% but no luck..
what i am missing...?Please help me out...bold code in test class has not covered...

**Apex class:**

```
public with sharing class InvoiceGenerator {

public void generateInvoices() {  
    Invoice_Generation_Frequency__c igf = Invoice_Generation_Frequency__c.getInstance('Default');
    system.debug('igf.Days__c:'+igf.Days__c);

    Integer currentYear = system.today().year();
    Integer currentDay = (system.today().addDays((integer)igf.Days__c)).day();
    system.debug('--day--'+currentDay); 

    List<Account> accList = [Select Id,Group__c,Group_Signup_Start_Date__c,Group_Renewal_Date__c,Invoice_Amount__c From Account  where 

    Group__c='yes' and CALENDAR_YEAR(Group_Renewal_Date__c) < = :currentYear and DAY_IN_MONTH(Group_Renewal_Date__c) = :currentDay];

    String currYear = system.today().year() + '%';
    //List<AggregateResult> arList = [select count(id) cnt from Invoice__c where Invoice_Number__c like :currYear];
    //nextInvNum = (integer)arList[0].get('cnt');

    List<Invoice__c> invnumberList = [select Invoice_Number__c from Invoice__c where Invoice_Number__c like:currYear order by Invoice_Number__c desc];
    List<Invoice__c> InvoiceList = new List<Invoice__c>();

    if(invnumberList.size() > 0){  
        string invhighestnum = invnumberList[0].Invoice_Number__c;
        string convertedlast = invhighestnum.substring(5,9);
        integer InvNumhighest = integer.valueOf(convertedlast);
        system.debug('132654'+InvNumhighest);  

        system.debug('--InvNumhighestnew--'+InvNumhighest);  
        for(Account a : accList) {
            InvNumhighest++;
            Invoice__c Inv = new Invoice__c();
            Inv.Account__c = a.Id;  
            Inv.Paid__c = false; 
            Inv.Group_Start_Date__c = a.Group_Signup_Start_Date__c;
            Inv.Group_Renewal_Date__c = a.Group_Renewal_Date__c; 
            Inv.Invoice_Amount__c = a.Invoice_Amount__c;  
            Inv.Invoice_Number__c = (system.today().year() + '-' + InvNumhighest);
            InvoiceList.add(Inv);
            system.debug('--invList--'+InvoiceList); 
        }
        insert InvoiceList;
    }   
    else {
            **integer nextInvNum;
            nextInvNum = 0000;                   
            nextInvNum = nextInvNum + 2000;
            system.debug('--nextInvNum--'+nextInvNum);
            for(Account a : accList) {
                nextInvNum++;
                Invoice__c Inv = new Invoice__c();
                Inv.Account__c = a.Id;  
                Inv.Paid__c = false; 
                Inv.Start_Date__c = a.Group_Signup_Start_Date__c;
                Inv.Renewal_Date__c = a.Group_Renewal_Date__c; 
                Inv.Invoice_Amount__c = a.Invoice_Amount__c;
                Inv.Invoice_Number__c = (system.today().year() + '-' + nextInvNum);
                InvoiceList.add(Inv);  
            }
            insert InvoiceList;** 
        }                          
  }
}
```

**Test class:**

```
 @isTest(SeeAllData=true)
 class TestInvoiceUpdate{


public static String CRON_EXP = '0 00 01 * * ?';

static testmethod void test() {

Test.startTest();

Account a = new Account();
a.Name = 'test';
a.Group__c = 'Yes';
Date myDate = date.newinstance((system.today().addYears(-1)).year(), (system.today().addDays(45)).month(), (system.today().addDays(45)).day());
a.Group_Renewal_Date__c = myDate;
insert a;
system.debug('Myinsert'+a);

Invoice__c i = new Invoice__c();
i.Paid__c = false;
i.Account__c = a.id;
i.Invoice_Number__c = '1111';
insert i;

String InvId = System.schedule('testBasicScheduledApex',CRON_EXP,new InvoiceUpdate());
// Get the information from the CronTrigger API object
CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :InvId];
// Verify the expressions are the same 
System.assertEquals(CRON_EXP, ct.CronExpression);
// Verify the job has not run 
System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);
Test.stopTest();

}

static testmethod void test1() {

Test.startTest();

Account a = new Account();
a.Name = 'test1';
a.Group__c = 'Yes';
Date myDate1 = date.newinstance((system.today().addYears(-1)).year(), (system.today().addDays(45)).month(), (system.today().addDays(45)).day());
a.Group_Renewal_Date__c = myDate1;
insert a;
system.debug('Myinsert'+a);

Invoice__c i = new Invoice__c();
i.Paid__c = false;
i.Account__c = a.id;
i.Invoice_Number__c = '2222';
insert i;

String InvId = System.schedule('testBasicScheduledApex',CRON_EXP,new InvoiceUpdate());
// Get the information from the CronTrigger API object
CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :InvId];
// Verify the expressions are the same 
System.assertEquals(CRON_EXP, ct.CronExpression);
// Verify the job has not run 
System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);
Test.stopTest();
   }     
}
```

Comment: According to your `System.debug()` lines, could you able to find out which lines are not get covered?

Comment: Screen from Developer Console or more specific question would be helpful :)

Comment: The Developer Console usually shows the untested lines of your code. Screenshot of this would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Your test code calls the InvoiceUpdate class, but you have only shown us the InvoiceGenerator class. Therefore, we cannot know why the class is not covered in your test code.

From the code you have shared, you should have ZERO percent coverage.